# Get index of jquery object within another jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose

```
<div class='foo' id='a'></div>
<div class='foo' id='b'></div>
<div class='foo' id='c'></div>
```

`var foos = $('.foo');`

we can get the first foo if we want

`var myFoo = $(foos.get(0));`

Now that we have `myFoo`, how can we do the opposite to get its index?

`var index = foos.getIndexOf(myFoo);`

Comment: JQuery's `index()` function is described here: https://api.jquery.com/index/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use [**`.index( element )`**](https://api.jquery.com/index/#index-element)

*If `.index()` is called on a collection of elements and a `DOM element` or `jQuery object` is passed in, `.index()` returns an integer indicating the position of the passed element relative to the original collection.*

```js
var foos = $('.foo');
var myFoo = $(foos.get(0));
console.log(foos.index(myFoo));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='foo' id='a'></div>
<div class='foo' id='b'></div>
<div class='foo' id='c'></div>
```